# 'Cannot GET/' error in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

This is a Node project, I'm getting a 'Cannot GET/' error when I try top open up localhost on port 8081. I'm almost certain it's just not reading in the HTML file correctly but I'm not sure.

```
var express = require('express');       
var jsonfile = require('jsonfile');  
var bodyParser = require('body-parser'); 



var app = express();
var file = 'C:/xampp/htdocs/codedb.json';


app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(express.static('codeStore'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());



app.get('/backEndVersion.html', function (req, res) {
   res.sendFile( __dirname + "/" + "backEndVersion.html" );
})
```

Comment: Check the version of express you are using in your package.json.

Comment: It's the same as what `npm express -v`is telling me, which is 5.0.3

Comment: but apparently that isn't the a version of Express, everything I check is giving me back version 5.0.3 so now I'm even more confused

Comment: Use `express --version` to check version of your express. `npm express -v` will give you the version available on npm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
app.get('/somepath',function(req,res){
   res.render('backEndVersion.html')
})
```

When u request somepath u will be rendered the backEndVersion.html  file

I suggest u better use ejs or hbs engine for html renderering in nodejs

[ejs link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ejs)

Answer (score -1):

I think you forgot to let the server listen to request. At the end of your file, add :

```
app.listen(8081)
```

Comment: If it's not the issue, you might want to add the route app.`get('/', function(req,res){...})`and see if it works

Comment: I've only shared part of the code as it's quite big, at the end I do have an app.listen.

Comment: When I use  `app.get('/', function (req, res) {
   res.sendFile( __dirname + "/" + "backEndVersion.html" );
})` It gives me back this: TypeError: res.sendFile is not a function

Comment: does res.end() work ? Your version of Express is probably not up to date : `sendFile()`is only supported by versions 4.8+

Comment: How would I use it here?

Comment: My version of express is 5.0.3 according to the terminal

Comment: Sad :/ If you do `app.get('/', function (req, res) { res.end(); })`, the server will respond with a blank page with status code 200